# How to detect a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitouch

HI
I have a UIScrollView
In this scrollView i have added an UIImage ,UILabel,UIButton.
I want to detect the double click of UIImage inside the UIScrollView.

```
-(void) touchesbegin:(NSSet *)touchs withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if([[touches anyObject]view]==??)
    {
       //MyCode on double tap of UIImageView inside UIScrollView
    }
}
```

what sholud i use in place of ?? to detect the UIImageView insde the UIScrollView.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find the answer in the following sample code.

- [TapDetectingImageView.h](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/1_TapToZoom_Classes_TapDetectingImageView_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-1_TapToZoom_Classes_TapDetectingImageView_h-DontLinkElementID_7)
- [TapDetectingImageView.m](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/1_TapToZoom_Classes_TapDetectingImageView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904-1_TapToZoom_Classes_TapDetectingImageView_m-DontLinkElementID_8)

This sample codes are come from Apple. You can find those sample codes at the UIImageView Class Reference.